# Bison, Specify Token numeric code from macro

Tags: c, bison

I create a custom compiler with flex/bison, and I have a TokenTypes.h file, where I define all my token type codes. I use those codes extensively through the program, so I thought is better to define them myself and maintain control over them, instead of letting bison do it. The TokenTypes.h looks like that:

```
#define TokenType_INT 1
#define TokenType_PLUS 2
//...
```

My problem is that I haven't figure out how to tell bison to use those numeric codes. I read in the docs that I can specify them literally:

```
%token INTEGER 1
```

but I do not want to hardcode the number (in this example 1) again here, since it is defined in TokenTypes.h and I was hoping that I dont have to repeat and maintain all the definitions in 2 places.

I tried using the #define'd key TokenType_INT instead of its value (1) in my %token declaration, but this made bison fail:

```
In file included from ../data/syntax.y:11:0,
                 from ../src/Compiler.c:15:
../src/parser/../lexer/TokenTypes.h:3:31: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
 #define TokenType_INT      1
                               ^
../src/parser/autoGenerated.Syntax.h:73:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘TokenType_INT’
     TokenType_INT = 259,
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../data/lex.l:12:0:
../src/lexer/TokenTypes.h:3:31: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
 #define TokenType_INT      1
```

**EDIT**: For anyone who might have the same question as I had:
As the comments on my post already suggested, this is not possible and not desired in Bison, so I will give up the idea and let bison define the values.

Comment: You seem to redefine the token types in the Bison file. Only define them in the Bison file, a header file with the tokens and their values will be generated.

Comment: Bison will also know what values are available too since I would imagine that you're going to run into conflicts with character literals if you start at 1.

Comment: Ok, then I will give up defining them myself and rely on bison, as you mentioned.. At least for the terminals.
One clarification please on that, do bison assign numeric codes to non terminals too that I could use in the rest of my program? Or I have to define those myself?

Comment: See, the problem clearly here is that Bison is already generating an `enum` for these tokens